# Regexpr with lookaround in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to get the **value of bgcol** in the string (255;0;0).

I didn't manage to figure out lookaheads in R, which should be useful for this task, so I had to combine a `regexpr+regmatches` with 2 subsequent `gsub` calls.

```
string <- "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"248;186;203\" col=\"0;200;0\"/>"
string <- "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"255;0;0\"/>"


bgcol = regmatches(string, regexpr('(bgcol=\"(.*)\")', string, perl=TRUE))
bgcol = gsub(pattern = "\"", replacement="", bgcol)
bgcol = gsub(pattern = "bgcol=", replacement="", bgcol)

as.integer(strsplit(bgcol, ";")[[1]])
```

> [1] 255   0   0

How can I simplify / beautify the regular expressions above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may either use a `regmatches`/`regexec`:

```
string <- "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"255;0;0\"/>"
lapply(strsplit(regmatches(string, regexec('bgcol="([^"]*)"', string))[[1]][2], ";"), as.integer)
## => [[1]]
##    [1] 255   0   0
```

The `bgcol="([^"]*)"` pattern matches `bgcol="`, then matches and captures any 0+ chars other than `"` into Group 1 ([`regexec`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) keeps track of all captured substrings), and then matches a `"`.

Or a PCRE pattern with `regmatches`/`regexpr`:

```
lapply(strsplit(regmatches(string, regexpr('bgcol="\\K[^"]*', string, perl=TRUE)), ";"), as.integer)
## => [[1]]
##    [1] 255   0   0
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/jaTilE)

The `bgcol="\\K[^"]*` pattern matches `bgcol="` and then this text is dropped from the match with the help of `\K` match reset operator, and only the text matched with `[^"]*` remains in the match.

And just for completeness, `stringr` solutions:

```
> library(stringr)
> lapply(strsplit(str_extract(string, '(?<=bgcol=")[^"]*'), ";"), as.integer)
[[1]]
[1] 255   0   0

> lapply(strsplit(str_match(string, 'bgcol="([^"]*)"')[,2], ";"), as.integer)
[[1]]
[1] 255   0   0
```

Note that the `(?<=bgcol=")` in the `str_extract` function only checks for `bgcol="` immediately to the left of the current location, so it is not part of the match.

Comment: Allthough both answers work, you definitly deserve this check for the very nice explanation and the different options! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern `'.*bgcol=\"(\\d*;\\d*;\\d*)\"\\s?.*'`

```
> bgcol <- gsub('.*bgcol=\"(\\d*;\\d*;\\d*)\"\\s?.*', "\\1", strings)
> lapply(strsplit(bgcol, ";"), as.integer)
[[1]]
[1] 255   0   0

[[2]]
[1] 248 186 203
```

Comment: This works very nice, but only if there is nothing else after the bgcol. I'll include another example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `read.table`

```
read.table(text = gsub('.*bgcol.*?(\\d+;\\d+;\\d+).*', '\\1', string), sep=';')
   V1  V2  V3
1 248 186 203
2 255   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had your data in a nice little dataframe, like:

```
df <- tibble(string <- c("<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"248;186;203\" col=\"0;200;0\"/>",
            "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"255;0;0\"/>"))
```

Then you could just do this

```
  df %>% mutate(bgcol.value = str_extract(string, "\\d+;\\d+;\\d+")) 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `string <- c("<params description=\\"some desc\\" bgcol=\\"248;186;203\\" … bgcol.value
  <chr>                                                                       <chr>      
1 "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"248;186;203\" col=\"0;200;0\"/>" 248;186;203
2 "<params description=\"some desc\" bgcol=\"255;0;0\"/>"                     248;186;203
```